# How to make screen responsive flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to make a screen responsive according all phone size:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use any package from below to make your app responsive

[responsive_framework: ^0.2.0](https://pub.dev/packages/responsive_framework)

[flutter_screenutil: ^5.5.4](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil)

Comment: I want to make my whole app responsive how i can use these packages?

Comment: responsive_framework: ^0.2.0 will work for the whole app just set it in the material app. @HimaniUpadhyay